# WebView File Picker (Android) with onShowFileChooser refreshes app on closing the dialog

Tags: android, file-upload, webview

I have a WebView app that allows users to select and upload a file using an `<input type="file">`.
However, when I close the file selection dialog (either by selecting a file, or cancelling), my WebView app resets: it refreshes to the homepage.

```
@SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            
            if (Config.requireStorage && Config.requireCamera) {
                String[] perms = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA};

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                        && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, perms, FCR);

                } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, FCR);

                } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, FCR);
                } else if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, FCR);
                }

                if (mUMA != null) {
                    mUMA.onReceiveValue(null);
                }
                mUMA = filePathCallback;

                if (Arrays.asList(fileChooserParams.getAcceptTypes()).contains("audio/*")) {
                    Intent chooserIntent = fileChooserParams.createIntent();
                    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CODE_AUDIO_CHOOSER);
                    return true;
                }

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    File photoFile = null;
                    try {
                        photoFile = createImageFile();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                    }
                    if (photoFile != null) {
                        mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, getPackageName() + ".provider", photoFile));
                    } else {
                        takePictureIntent = null;
                    }
                }
                Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
                if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                    File videoFile = null;
                    try {
                        videoFile = createVideoFile();
                        takeVideoIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mVM);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Video file creation failed", ex);
                    }
                    if (videoFile != null) {
                        mVM = "file:" + videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                        takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                                FileProvider.getUriForFile(MainActivity.this, getPackageName() + ".provider", videoFile));
                    } else {
                        takeVideoIntent = null;
                    }
                }


                Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                contentSelectionIntent.setDataAndType(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "image/* video/*");
                contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[]{"image/*", "video/*"});


                Intent[] intentArray;
                if (takePictureIntent != null && takeVideoIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent, takeVideoIntent};
                } else if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
                } else if (takeVideoIntent != null) {
                    intentArray = new Intent[]{takeVideoIntent};
                } else {
                    intentArray = new Intent[0];
                }

                Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Upload");
                chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
                startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FCR);
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Does anyone know how I can just make the `<input type="file">` work, so that it holds the file and when I submit the form I can handle this file?

Comment: Override onSaveInatanceState() to save the state. Get the state back in onCreate from the state parameter.

Comment: What happens now if you rotate the device?

Comment: @blackapps I'm not sure exactly what you mean. As you can maybe tell, I am a web developer, not an Android developer (hence I am using webview). My app doesn't rotate (it is portrait only).